# ExpressionEngine 5 - Cookie Consent Solutions

Tags: cookies, expressionengine

looking for cookie consent solutions for EE5, also open to 3rd party solutions.

The built-in EE cookie consent module does not come with CSS to stick the form to the bottom of the page, maybe somebody can share their solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EE doesn't care where or what you do with the cookie consent. If you create a div an stick it to the bottom you can fill it with the consent stuff and show it only if they haven't yet granted consent:

```
{if ! consent_granted}
    <div>..</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: can you provide a code example on how to stick the div to the bottom ?